# What word means dealing with the insignificant?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word that fits in to this sentence and means dealing with the insignificant:

> *Twins* fans have a knack for fretting over the ______, and this won't
>   relent any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minutiae** fits your sentence. It is a plural noun

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minutiae

“a minute or minor detail —usually used in plural
He was bewildered by the contract's minutiae.“

Answer (score 2):

> trifle  -- n. a thing of little value or importance.

Or *trivial,* inconsequential, ..

Answer (score 0):

As in:

Twins fans have a knack for fretting over a **whit**, and this won't relent anytime soon.

a **whit**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228558?rskey=SDOzbQ&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Without negative: **a whit**: to a very small extent, a very little.
>   any whit, one whit: to the least amount, in the least degree, at all.
>   every (†each) whit: completely, altogether, thoroughly, quite (in
>   later use almost always with as in comparisons of equality).

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly different tone, how about *fretting over [ephemera](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemera).*

According to the Wilipedia, *ephemera* is derived from the Greek words *epi* (for)
and *hemera* (a day). It usually means “insignificant” and/or “short-lived”.

*Minutae*, offered by a previous poster, means “small in space”. *Ephemera* means “small in time”.

Depending on the subject of the fretting, and whether you’re trying to be serious or ironic, either might be a usable choice.